# Изменение курсора в FigureCanvasQTAgg

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я уже задавал вопрос по поводу изменения курсора в `tkinter`, а теперь застрял в `PYQT`.  Имеется гуи, с расположенным на ней табами и канвасом, в котором строится график. Суть - когда нажимается кнопка "Нижняя граница", в пределах осей курсор должен менять форму. Пробовал так же, как и в случае с ткинтером, выкидывает

> `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'configure'.|`

Еще есть очень хороший курсор в `matplotlib.widgets - Cursor`, но неясно, как его привязать к `NavigationToolbar2QT`, а хотелось бы.

```
class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2QT):
    def _set_cursor(self, event):
        if event.inaxes and self._active == 'CUSTOM_LIMIT':
            self.window.configure(cursor='crosshair')
            self._lastCursor = None
            return
        NavigationToolbar2QT._set_cursor(self, event)


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        title = 'Test'
        left = 50
        top = 80
        width = 1000
        height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab2 = QWidget()
        self.addTab(tab1, "Исходный сигнал")
        self.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2")
        tab1.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        frame1=QFrame()
        frame2 = QFrame()

        tab1.layout.addWidget(frame1)
        tab1.layout.addWidget(frame2)

        frame1.layout = QFormLayout(self)
        frame2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.titleEdit = QLineEdit()
        pushButton1 = QPushButton("Нижняя граница")
        pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.connect_canv)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg. (self.figure)
        self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.canvas, tab1)

        frame1.layout.addRow(self.titleEdit, pushButton1)
        frame2.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        frame2.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        frame1.setLayout(frame1.layout)
        frame2.setLayout(frame2.layout)
        tab1.setLayout(tab1.layout)

    def getXY(self, event):
        x, y = event.inaxes.transData.inverted().transform((event.x,                         
        event.y))
        getx = event.x
        if self.titleEdit.text() == '':
            self.titleEdit.insert(str('%1.2f' % x))
            self.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        else:
            pass

    def connect_canv(self):

        self.titleEdit.clear()
        global cid
        self.toolbar._active = 'CUSTOM_LIMIT'
        cid = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', 
        self.getXY)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: попробовал в методе def _set_cursor вставить setOverrideCursor вместо window.configure, курсор меняется, но флаг не срабатывает и за пределами осей курсор не меняется на стрелку.

Comment: Вам лучше сократить код вопроса и оставить только касающееся проблемы. Т.к. на данный момент ваш код даже нельзя запустить. Например, `self.canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg. (self.figure)` - это как понимать?

Comment: Замените `self.window.configure(cursor='crosshair')` на `self.set_cursor(Qt.%выбранный_курсор%)`